# Polymorphic associations with SailsJS

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I use sailsJS to built a REST API that , takes advantage of the Blueprints.

My Design has a lot of resource in which one is a Asset resource :

```
Asset ( id, type, owner_type, owner_id, url);
```

This will act as an entry point to host multiple assets for any other resource in the system.

ie.

User Resource can have multiple images and a video. All of these records gets stored under the Asset Resource.

```
Asset ( id, type, owner_type, owner_id, url);
Asset ( 1, 'image', 'User', 1, 'http://path.to.image.com/abc.jpg');
Asset ( 2, 'video', 'User', 1, 'https://youtube.com/sdasd');
Asset ( 3, 'image', 'BlogPost', 20, 'http://path.to.image.com/blogpost.jpg');
```

So ideally when i do a Get user by ID or Get All users , I would prefer to get the related assets for that object.

Its possible to prepare the response if I am implementing the two methods to GetOne and GetAll , but when consuming the Blueprints its a bit blurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correct, you have User model, then you have an Asset model.

The User model looks like

```
//User.js
module.exports={
    assets:{collection:'Asset',via:'owner_id'}
}
```

The Asset model should looks like

```
module.exports={
    type:'string',
    owner_type:'string',
    owner_id:{model:'User'},
    url:'string'
}
```

You will not be able to use the blueprint directly, but you could do something like this:

```
//UserController.js
module.exports={
    findOne:function(req,res){
        User.findOne(req.param.id).populate('assets',{owner_type:'User'}).exec(function(data){res.json(data)});
    },
    find:function(req,res){
       User.find().populate.....//same idea
   }

}
```

This populate parameter {owner_type} is the populate options, so that it only populate the collection of assets, which has owner_type is "User", you can also specify limit, like the documentation [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/247), unfortunately I didn't find official documentations for this, sails and waterline is still a young framework, lots of unclear documentations and stuff, but I think you have made a right choice for using it. Let me know if it helps.

EDIT: This just work with User, if you have a Blog model also need to populate it, then you can do it manually

```
//Blog.js
var Promise=require('bluebird');
module.exports={
    findOne:function(req,res){
        Promise.all([Blog.findOne(req.param.id),
        Asset.find({owner_id:req.param.id,owner_type:'blog'})])
        .spread(function(blog,assets){
            blog.assets=assets
            return req.json(blog);
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: There is also some official documentation here that might help: http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/OnetoMany.html

Comment: @Evilsanta well the owner_id is not always a User , it will change. So basically 1 use case it could be assets that belong to a User , for another it could be assets that belong to a Blog Post. The owner_type will store the model type ( User , BlogPost )

Comment: @GayanL yes, I am afraid you can only choose one to populate the collection. My example only let you to get the assets of a user, but you won't be able to do Blogpost.populate. Sorry for this disappointment, but you can certainly manually do it with a two step process.Let me know if you need more help

Comment: @Evilsanta great , since there is no native implementation overriding for each time I need the polymorphic implementation is needed.

Comment: @GayanL actually in my own experience I don't like using the native blueprints for the major models like blog or user. Because the populate is significantly slower when u populate a m to m or one to m. I just turn off default populate and I usually write code for the find method. And it wouldn't take much to implement ur self

Comment: @Evilsanta yeah completely agree on that +1

Answer (score 2):

Try my Polymorphic, deep and inclusive populat hook: [sails-hook-deep-orm](http://github.com/emahuni/sails-hook-deep-orm) it addresses polymorphic associations and more.

## Features:

- Polymorphic Populations

  - eg: `js let Results = await Status.find().populate('*');`
- Deep Populations

  - eg: `js let Results = await Person.find().populate('home.occupants.statuses.*');`
- Inclusive Criteria Populations

  - eg: `js let Results = await Person.find().populate('home.occupants&state.statuses&phones.*&network');`
- Deep Wild Object and Array Utils

  - eg: `js sails.hooks.deeporm.wild.get(Records, "*.home.occupants.*.phones.0.number");`